# How to pick the topx rows inside categories inside intervals in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like this

```
test <- data.table(variable=c(rep(1:5,100)),percent=abs(rnorm(500,0,1)),select=c(501:1000))
```

What I would like to do is: for every `variable`, `%>%` create 5% intervals (e.g [0, 0.05) , [0.05, 0.1), [0.1, 0.15) ), so in the end i would have `20*5` intervals and then, inside these intervals pick the top(x) `select`.

**UPDATE**

```
> test[,cut(percent,20),by="variable"]
     variable             V1
  1:        1  (0.726,0.841]
  2:        1  (0.496,0.611]
  3:        1  (0.266,0.381]
```

`cut` does not work the way i would like to, because i do not get the desired intervals

Comment: You can use `cut` to create the intervals

Comment: i thought that `cut` gives equally sized (in terms of population) intervals, whereas i would like, equally sized intervals in terms of length.

Comment: Do it in multiple steps. First create a factor of the quantile in each group, then do the selection by grouping by the interaction of the quantile with the group. Functions which might be useful for this are: `cut`,  `interaction`, `rank`, `order`, `quantile`

Comment: @quant you can define the breaks for cut. If i understand you correctly, what you want is something like: `seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=20)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
breaks <- seq(0, 1, by=0.05) # this works better than length.out=20, because you 
                             # avoid round errors
test[,interval:=cut(percent,breaks=breaks),by="variable"]
setkey(test,variable,percent)
test2 <- test[,tail(.SD,20),by=.(variable,interval)]
```

Comment: There is no need to cut by group; it should work the same with or without group. In light of that, it looks like you can do `test[, tail(.SD, 20), by=.(variable, interval = cut(percent, breaks = breaks))]` or similar.